# POJO Object not converting to JSON Object

Tags: java, json, jersey

Im trying to write a REST service that will take a binary data and return JSON OBject.

REST Service:

```
public class FileUpload {

    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Result uploadFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream) {
        String uploadedFileLocation = "c://tomcatupload/" + filename;

        // save it
        writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

        String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

        //return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
        Result result = new Result("status","success");

        return result;

    }
}
```

RESULT OBject

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

public class Result {
    private String Status;
    private String result;
    public Result(){

    }
    public Result(String status, String result){
        this.Status = status;
        this.result = result;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return Status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        Status = status;
    }
    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }
    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return new StringBuffer("result : ").append(this.result).toString();
    }

}


public class FileUploadClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException{
        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = client
                   .resource("http://localhost:8080/RESTFileAttachmentService/rest/file/upload");
        String fileName = "C:/test.txt";
        InputStream fileInStream = null;
        try {
            fileInStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found exception");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //String sContentDisposition = "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName.getName()+"\"";
        //WebResource fileResource = a_client.resource(a_sUrl);
        System.out.println("Webservice is being called = " + fileInStream);
        ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).accept("application/json")
                                .post(ClientResponse.class, fileInStream);
        System.out.println("Webservice call over = " + response.getStatus());
        System.out.println("Webservice call over = " + response.getEntity(Result.class));

    }
}
```

Ouptut:

```
result : success
```

I'm not sure why its not printing the output as JSON Object. This looks like a raw String.

Error when I print the String.class directly -

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.owlike.genson.JsonBindingException: Could not deserialize to type class java.lang.String
    at com.owlike.genson.ext.jaxrs.GensonJsonConverter.readFrom(GensonJsonConverter.java:127)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:553)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:506)
    at com.gsa.gov.file.upload.FileUploadClient.main(FileUploadClient.java:37)
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>esoa</groupId>
    <artifactId>RESTFileAttachmentService</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RESTFileAttachmentService Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>

        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId> <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId> 
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
            <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
            <version>0.99</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <finalName>RESTFileAttachmentService</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You say JSON, but you're annotating it with something to do with XML?

Comment: Should I explicitly add quotes to looks like JSON OBject or the conversion should automatically happen?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested, but it's most likely due to the fact that you are printing the `Result` object, which will print the `toString`. If you want the raw JSON, then use `response.getEntity(String.class)`. When you use `getEntity(Result.class)`, then the raw JSON is converted to a `Result` object.

Comment: You could be right but I get a different error when I display the string. I have given the error.

Comment: I don't (or ever really) use Genson as the provider. Can you post the Maven dependency. Also if need to configure Genson in any way, can you post those configurations, so I can test. Seems to be a problem with Genson, as I never have any problems with this with the normal JSON provider

Comment: If I don't use Genson, I get a different error ie; it could not write JSON Response.

Comment: See near the bottom of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27355016/2587435). You already have the `jersey-json` provider, but there are a couple other configurations need with it. Then comment out all the Genson stuff. I'm not sure if it auto-registers itself or not (don't want it to conflict)

Comment: For the server side, you can use either the web.xml or the programmatic configuration (it's mainly just enable the pojo mapping feature). With the client, the same is needed also, if you want to map back to `Result`. If you just want the raw JSON using `getEntity(String.class)`, then enabling this feature on the client is not necessary.

Comment: Also I noticed you have the `jersey-json` provider in a `provided` scope, but all your other jersey dependencies are not. You might want to get rid of that `provided` scope also

Comment: So I just tested it, and it _is_ a problem with Genson. With what? I don't know, as I said I don't use Genson. But using the `jersey-json` provider and getting rid of Genson works fine.

Comment: Alternatively, you can get the `InputStream` with `response.getEntityInputStream()`, and just read the JSON from the InputStream, but I have figure out how to auto convert it to String with Genson

Comment: I deleted all the jars and rebuilt it again..its working now..I see the results in JSON format but really not sure what fixed the issue.

Comment: Even with using just Genson, without any of the jersey-json configuration? Because I was not able to get it to work with Genson alone (reading straight to String)

Comment: Here are the jars in the lib - asm-3.1.jar, genson-0.99jar,jersey-bundle-1.18.1.jar,jersey-client-1.8.jar,jersey-core-1.8.jar,jersey-multipart-1.8.jar,jersey-server-1.8.jar,jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar,mimepull-1.4.jar