# Use custom object to receive json response for Rest API

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client

I have set up a rest API service using Jersey which produces an json response. This is the server code:

```
@Path("/addNumservice")
public class AddNumService {
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response addNum() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        int x = 5, y = 4;
        int z = x + y; 
        jsonObject.put("Sum Value", z); 

        String result = "@Produces(\"application/json\") Output: \n\nNumber adding Output: \n\n" + jsonObject;
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
    }
}
```

When I run the server, I see the o/p as expected:

```
@Produces("application/json") Output: 
Number adding Output: 
{"Sum Value":9}
```

Now I want to set up a client class to receive the json response in a custom object which I have defined, `AddNumResponseObject`, but when I do this:

```
AddNumResponseObject object
      = webResource2.accept("application/json").get(AddNumResponseObject.class);
```

> I get this error: A message body reader for Java class com.crunchify.client.AddNumResponseObject, and Java type class com.crunchify.client.AddNumResponseObject, and MIME media type application/json was not found

Can someone please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a provider to your project that supports JSON to POJO (and vice-versa). Now I'm making the assumption here that you are using Jersey 1 (as inferred by the name `webResource2`). In which case, you should add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then register it with the client

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
//config.getClasses().add(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
config.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, 
                                               Boolean.TRUE);
Client c = Client.create(config);
```

For server configuration (if needed) or Jersey 2 support, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27355016/2587435). Also see [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/user-guide.html#json.pojo.approach.section)