# No message body writer has been found for response class when accessing the service

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, wso2-identity-server

I have a jax-rs endpoint as below.

```
@GET
@Path("/")
@Produces("application/json")
public OPLogin getLoginStatus(@Context HttpServletRequest request) throws URISyntaxException {
    OPLogin opLogin = new OPLogin();
    String commonAuthCookie = null;
    SessionContext sessionContext = null;
    if (FrameworkUtils.getAuthCookie(request) != null) {
        commonAuthCookie = FrameworkUtils.getAuthCookie(request).getValue();
    }
    if (commonAuthCookie != null) {
        sessionContext = FrameworkUtils.getSessionContextFromCache(commonAuthCookie);
    }
    if (sessionContext != null) {
        Map<String, AuthenticatedIdPData> authenticatedIDPMap = sessionContext.getAuthenticatedIdPs();
        if (authenticatedIDPMap.size() > 0) {
            Iterator it = authenticatedIDPMap.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
                it.remove();
                AuthenticatedIdPData authenticatedIdPData = (AuthenticatedIdPData) pair.getValue();
                if (authenticatedIdPData.getIdpName().equals("LOCAL")) {
                    opLogin.setLoginStatus(true);
                    break;
                } else {
                    opLogin.setLoginStatus(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
  return opLogin;
}
```

I have a separate OPLogin class with a property of loginStatus.

This service is hosted in wso2 IS. when I'm accessing this web service trough a browser it gives the following error.

No message body writer has been found for response class OPLogin. When I debug the code it does not throw any exception. It successfully returns true. But It publishes such a message. Any help is highly appreciated.
web.xml

```
   <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>OAuth2 Endpoints</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>OAuth2Endpoints</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>OAuth2Endpoints</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't use WSO server, but does it come equipped with a JAX-RS implementation, or are you explicitly using your own implementation?

Comment: WSO2 Identity Server supports for JAX-RS implementation.

Comment: How do you compile your code? What jars do you include? And do you know the JAX-RS implementation and version it uses?

Comment: I am debugging the code using a JAX-RS client. The problem occurs when I'm using ("application/json") for @Produces. Otherwise if I use ("text/plain") or other thing it works fine

Comment: Well since you are not answering my question, I'll just tell you that mostly you need a JSON provider implementation. LIke [this one from Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers)

Comment: yep I'm using Jersey as the implementation

Comment: Are you using Maven? And do yo know which Jersey version? Also can you show how you configure the application (either web.xml or ResourceConfig)

Comment: yep I'm using maven. Using jersey 1.8.  I added web.xml to the question

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27355016/2587435) should give you all you need (dependency and configuration)

Comment: Do you have a `ResourceConfig` or `Application` subclass in the project?. I am not seeing any Jersey configuration in your web.xml. Looks like CXF

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the problem is with your Java to Json conversion. First try to return a hard corded json string from your getLoginStatus method and see whether that works, if working , then you should check on the java to json conversion.

suggestions, 
* Make the OPLogin class a POJO 
* check whether you have the appropriate libraries placed