# Internal Server Error when trying to send pojo class object in response on rest using jersey

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I have a ResponseModel class, I want  to send it's object in response to rest. But I am getting this error:   A message body writer for Java class com.tcs.srl.message.model.ResponseModel, and Java type class com.tcs.srl.message.model.ResponseModel, and MIME media type application/json was not found

```
package com.tcs.DataShare.WebService;

import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.tcs.DataShare.Client.DataShareServiceClient;
import com.tcs.DataShare.Client.GetFilesOnLocal;
import com.tcs.DataShare.Constants.DataShareConstants;
import com.tcs.srl.message.model.ResponseModel;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;

@Path("/ConfigureAndrew")
public class ConfigureAndrew {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(ConfigureAndrew.class);
    private ClientResponse response;

    @Path("/configureAndrew")
    @POST
    //@Produces("application/octet-stream")
    // @Produces("application/xml")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response configureAndrew(@Context HttpServletRequest requestObj,
            String serviceData) {
        System.out.println("methods");
        LOGGER.debug("Inside Configure Andrew web service: ");
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        ResponseModel result = new ResponseModel();
        // JSONObject result=null;
        String isSuccess = "false";

        try {

            String headerString = requestObj.getHeader("header");

            JSONObject serviceJSON = (JSONObject) parser.parse(serviceData);

            String datashareURL = (String) serviceJSON
                    .get(DataShareConstants.DATASHARE_URL);

            String datasharePort = (String) serviceJSON
                    .get(DataShareConstants.DATASHARE_PORT);
            System.out.println("datasharePort: " + datasharePort);
            String servicename = (String) serviceJSON
                    .get(DataShareConstants.SERVICE_NAME);
            String appname = (String) serviceJSON
                    .get(DataShareConstants.APP_NAME);
            String version = (String) serviceJSON
                    .get(DataShareConstants.APP_VERSION);
            String path = (String) serviceJSON.get(DataShareConstants.APP_PATH);

            DataShareServiceClient dataShareServiceClient = new DataShareServiceClient(
                    datashareURL, datasharePort, servicename);
            InputStream inputStream = dataShareServiceClient
                    .zipFolderWithSubsequestFolder(path);
            if (inputStream.available() != 0) {
                System.out.println("In the input stream");
                GetFilesOnLocal getFilesOnLocal = new GetFilesOnLocal();
                 result = getFilesOnLocal.getFiles(inputStream, result);
                LOGGER.debug("Input stream contains data");
            } else {
                LOGGER.error("Input stream is empty");
                 System.out.println("error in input stream");
            }
            LOGGER.debug("DatashareServices :completed configure Andrew");
            isSuccess = "true";

            result.setSuccess("true");
            result.setErrors(null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOGGER.error("DatashareServices :configureAndrew service failed "
                    + e);
            isSuccess = "false";
            result.getErrors().add("Error in configureAndrew method");
            }

        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();

    }

}


Response Model POJO class::
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class ResponseModel implements Serializable{
    String success;
    List errors;
    public String getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }
    public void setSuccess(String success) {
        this.success = success;
    }
    public List getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }
    public void setErrors(List errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }
    public List getWarnings() {
        return warnings;
    }
    public void setWarnings(List warnings) {
        this.warnings = warnings;
    }
    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    List warnings;
    Object data;
    String transactionId;

    public String getTransactionId() {
        return transactionId;
    }
    public void setTransactionId(String transactionId) {
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
    }
```

Comment: is the   System.out.println("methods");
 getting printed in logs ?

Comment: It is post method and you're posting some data. I think you need to add `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`

Comment: You most likely haven't added a JSON provider or have one and haven't registered it. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27355016/2587435)